# Rails how do I - export data with send_data then redirect_to a new page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that allows a user to download a generated CSV file. After the file is downloaded, I'd like to redirect the user to a new URL or action. Is there a trick to do a redirect after a send_data?

I want to do something like this (which doesn't work):

```
send_data(output,:type => content_type,:filename => "myfile.csv")
redirect_to :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'download_done'
```

Comment: what happens when you run the code that you gave as an example?

Comment: nothing- no download, no redirect. Seems send_data is considered a "render" by rails. I'd thought it'd cause an exception if that really was the case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`send_data` is a render, so you can't do anything after it in a controller method.

The ways around it all involve Javascript. Here's one way I hacked together and never really liked:

- user hits submit
- small window pops up and connects to the controller to download the file
- main window redirects to the next page

Eventually I turned file generation into a background job. Then the user went to a jobs page (that didn't need a subsequent redirect) to get the files.

Comment: This technique worked well until a user with IE6 and very strict browser security settings came along and it stopped working. I ended up using an <iframe> as the target of the download action which seems to work in all of my tested environments.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I have a download link in page 1 and after the successfull download, i just want to redirect them to page 1 ( same page which has the download link ). If you have a same case like mine, please do the below one.

Just add the `target="_blank"` in your download button/link. This is only for `send_data` render method. If you use `send_file`, you have to handle this in js.

It redirects to the separate page and pops up a download file save option. Once you saved, it closes the new tab and takes them to the page which you clicked the download button.

Comment: I worked hard to achieve send+redirect, failed many times and just had the ultimate facepalm moment when I read this answer. Sometimes the easiest solutions are the best!

Comment: It works but it's weird that it quickly opens up a new tab and then closes it when done..