# In rails can't we use send_file and redirect_to together? Gives Render and/or redirect were called multiple times error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my action :

```
def download
    @photo = Photo.friendly.find(params[:photo_id])
    if @photo.free?
        size = Size.find(params[:size])

        img = Magick::Image.read(@photo.file.file.file).first
        img.resize!(size.width, size.height)

        path = "#{Rails.root}/tempfreedownload/#{size.width}x#{size.height}-#{@photo.file.file.filename}"
        File.write(path, '')
        img.write path

        url1_data = open(path)
        send_file url1_data

        File.delete path
        img.destroy!

        downloads = @photo.downloads + 1
        @photo.update_attribute(:downloads, downloads)

        flash[:success] = 'Thanks for downloading this image!'
        redirect_to(@photo)
        return
    else
        render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false, status: 404
    end
end
```

What I want to do is send the image to download and then redirect to the photo url. The problem is, in here I get a `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times` error. How can I fix this?

Comment: for every action ..use either render or redirect_to.....can't use both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to send two responses. One being file data and one being a redirect. Rails doesn't allow you to do this in a controller. It can be achieved with javascript but it's a little hacky. See this: [Rails how do I - export data with send_data then redirect_to a new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699113/rails-how-do-i-export-data-with-send-data-then-redirect-to-a-new-page)

Comment: A good quote regarding the subject is "The only usable way I've ever gotten this to work is to open a new window and send the download from there.  The fact that Google and others do this makes me a little more comfortable, but on a whole I still think it sucks."

Comment: The reason I can't use a simple link for this is that I need to post some data with the request... Data entered to the form which will be used to generate the download.

Comment: Thanks :-) I found a way to open the form in a new window, download and then close :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, you cannot send two responses to a single request. It is like ping pong: there is only one pong after the ping. So you need another ping from the user to hit the ball again on your side.

So when you send the file, the page does not change but the user gets the file.

What about doing it the other way round?

First redirect to the (landing) page, the user should see after the request and then redirect to the download via sendfile.

I did it via a meta-tag, which allows a delay for the redirect to the download page so the landing page will load completely before the redirect starts. Second advantage: no javascript.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def redirect_later(url, msg, delay = 5)
        flash[:redirect_later] = {
            url: url,
            delay: delay,
            msg: msg,
        }
    end

end


module ApplicationHelper
    def redirect_later_tag
        return nil unless flash.key?(:redirect_later)

        url = flash[:redirect_later][:url]
        delay = flash[:redirect_later][:delay]
        flash.now[:notice] = flash[:redirect_later][:msg] % [delay]

        flash.delete(:redirect_later)

        tag("meta", 
            "http-equiv" => "refresh",
            content: "#{delay}; URL=#{url}")
    end
end


# in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb in the header section
# where the meta tags are put:

<%= redirect_later_tag %>
```

In your controller, split your controller action into two actions:

The first one collects all data which are needed to prepare the file to be downloaded and makes sure, they are correct.

In this action you redirect to the landing page. But before you redirect you do

```
redirect_later download_path, "Download starts in %d seconds."
# here comes your redirect to the landing page
```

download_path is the url to the second action, which prepares and serves the file via send_file.

You could even use the same action, if you can distinguish the request via the format of the file:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { # your code to redirect to the landing page}
    format.png { # your code to send the file via send_file}
end
```

But keep in mind, that you make sure, that "download_path" includes the format of the file to be downloaded, otherwise you are looping all 5 seconds from the landing page to the landing page.

If you want to be 100% sure, the user gets the file, you could provide a link to the file in the message as a fallback - just in case the redirect won't work.

If you prepare/generate the file to be download: do not generate it with the first request otherwise you need to find a way to keep it somewhere until the second request. Generate it in the second request.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this I think this will work fine :

```
def download
  @photo = Photo.friendly.find(params[:photo_id])
  if @photo.free?
    size = Size.find(params[:size])

    img = Magick::Image.read(@photo.file.file.file).first
    img.resize!(size.width, size.height)

    path = "#{Rails.root}/tempfreedownload/#{size.width}x#{size.height}-#{@photo.file.file.filename}"
    File.write(path, '')
    img.write path

    url1_data = open(path)
    send_file url1_data

    File.delete path
    img.destroy!

    downloads = @photo.downloads + 1
    @photo.update_attribute(:downloads, downloads)

    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for downloading this image!'
    redirect_to(@photo) and return
  else
    render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false, status: 404 and return
  end
end
```