# Generate XML file and redirect to other view with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I have a piece of code that generates an XML file. What I want to, and didn't find the solution, is to generate the XML file and ALSO redirect to another page, to give a feedback message.

My code is

```
def exportFiles
    @files=FileToExport.getComponentToExport
    recursive_tree= GitHubRepositorioService.getRecursiveTree('master')
    GitHubService.updateFiles(@files, recursive_tree)
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=>$stdout, :indent=>2)
    respond_to do |format|
     format.xml { send_data render_to_string(:exportFiles), filename: 'exported_module.xml', type: 'application/xml', disposition: 'attachment' }
    end
    FileToExport.setComponentToExport(nil)
  end
```

As I already use "respond_to" I can't use another redirect sentence... so, there is a way to generate (downloading) that file and redirect to other view?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible via the controller as you can't send two responses.

But you could do this via javascript for instance. See this topic for more info [Rails how do I - export data with send_data then redirect_to a new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699113/rails-how-do-i-export-data-with-send-data-then-redirect-to-a-new-page)