# File is not downloading to local PC

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.1
```

In app/controllers/fw_exports_controller.rb, I have:

```
def download_csv
  followed = Followed.find(params[:followed_id])
  file_path = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/csv_container/#{followed.screen_name}_locations.csv"
  send_file (file_path), :type => "text/csv", :disposition => 'inline'
  redirect_to root_path, notice: t('fw_exports.spreadsheet_export.download_ok')
end
```

When this executes, I see the following in my log file:

```
Started POST "/download_csv" for 75.151.110.193 at 2017-12-12 22:31:56 +0000
Processing by FwExportsController#download_csv as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "followed_id"=>"followed.1510895564.0013862", "button"=>""}
  Followed Load  SELECT  `followeds`.* FROM `followeds` WHERE `followeds`.`id` = 'followed.1510895564.0013862' LIMIT 1
  Sent file /home/fwtest/rails/csv_container/wm_locations.csv (0.2ms)
  Redirected to http://fwtest.myapp.com/
```

I verified that /home/fwtest/rails/csv_container/wm_locations.csv is there and it's a CSV, but nothing downloads to my local PC.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `redirect_to`. If you have both `send_file` and `redirect_to` you are sending two responses - file and redirect. You are redirecting to `root_path` and the download does not start.

Comment: How that going to cause the file to download? and if I remove the redirect_to, it's not going to redirect to home

Comment: You are trying to send two responses indeed. One work around could be to download the file via AJAX, then redirect if the request succeeds?

Comment: Believe me, I have tested this with the Rails 5.1.4 few seconds ago. It does not work with `redirect_to` (and works fine without it). About your second question - I found similar problem with `send_data` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/699411/2039726

Comment: OK, this worked. I did not realize that send_file was a re-direct