# Download and redirect in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to put a link to download pdf file on my Rails app and it works.
But after download I don't want users in `.../download_pdf.fr` page but I want to redirect them in index. 
I tried to put `redirect_to root_path` in download method in my controller but download didn't work with that. 
If you have any idea.

Thank you a lot

**Routes**

```
get 'download_pdf', to: "home#download_pdf"
```

**Controller**

```
    def download_pdf
        send_file "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/file.pdf", type: "application/pdf", x_sendfile: true
    end
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to "Télécharger", download_pdf_path, class:"button1" %>
```

Comment: Does this answer on your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699113/rails-how-do-i-export-data-with-send-data-then-redirect-to-a-new-page

Comment: A response in HTTP can't both send a file and a be a redirect. If you actually sent a location header that would be like telling the client that "what you are trying to download is really at this location - but here take this random garbage that I'm sending you". There are numerous workarounds for this problem that mostly involve javascript or rendering a "download page" with a "back" link.

Comment: Ok, good to know ! I gonna look for other solution thank you